# Remove animation when using auto layout constraints

Tags: swift, animation, constraints

I can remove animations when I'm not using auto layout:

```
let box = UIButton()
box.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
box.backgroundColor = .gray
box.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)

view.addSubview(box)

func resetAnimation(_ object: UIView?) {
    if let presentation = object?.layer.presentation() {
        object?.layer.frame = presentation.frame
    }

    object?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}    

func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let animations() {
        box.frame.origin.y = 150
    }

    let completion() {
        print("print if completed")
    }

    resetAnimation(box)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: animations) { if $0 { completion() } }
}
```

If I keep pressing this box before the animation has ended, the completion handler won't print the text.

But how do I do this when I'm using auto layout?

```
var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

let box = UIButton()
box.backgroundColor = .gray
box.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)

view.addSubview(box)

// Left out other constraints for clarity
constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: box, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

view.addConstraint(constraint)

func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    constraint.constant = 150

    let animations() {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    let completion() {
        print("print if completed")
    }

    resetAnimations(box)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: animations) { if $0 { completion() } }
}
```

In the last example, the completion handler will print out the text no matter what.

How can I remove the animation in the second example like the first example?

Comment: "remove animation" is one thing. "completion handler" is another. What real problem are you actually asking about?

Comment: @matt: From what I've understood is: if I want to prevent the completion handler to execute, I have to remove the animation. So my question is, how can I remove the animation when using auto layout.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the completion handler from executing? And why do you think removing the animation is the way to do that? (Sounds rather drastic to me.) What's the real goal here?

Comment: @matt Using my first example, if the completion handler removes the box from view, then if I don't prevent the handler from executing then after 1 press the box will be removed from the view. It's my understanding that if I remove the animations using: `object.layer.removeAllAnimations()` it'll will prevent the completion handler in the `UIView.animate()`. Perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Comment: "Perhaps there's a better way to do this" Perhaps, but I still don't understand what "this" is. You have never stopped to explain what you are ultimately trying to do.